# Large out-of-range numbers appear in C++ rand()

Tags: c++, random

Need to have an array full of random numbers within range. Code:

```
void fillArray(int *arr){
        for(int i=0;i<(sizeof arr);i++){
            arr[i] = rand() % 2 - 2;
            }
        }

int *arrPoint(int *arr, int max){
    for (int i=0;i<max;i++){
        printf("%d is %d\n",i,arr[i]);
    }
    return arr;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int arr_f[15];
    fillArray(arr_s);
    arrPoint(arr_s, 15);
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
    0 is -2
1 is -1
2 is -2
3 is -1
4 is 0
5 is 0
6 is 4633240
7 is 2686652
8 is 1973724226
9 is 1974338216
10 is 2686716
11 is 1973744850
12 is 8
13 is 1973752206
14 is 1973752162
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What the hell? Putting rand() % 2 into brackets doesn't help either. What these numbers are and how do I get rid of them?

**P.S.** Tried this in crappy Dev-C++ and Code::Blocks with the same result. Need the program to be small sized (putting it to dropbox), so no, I *can't* use 100mb boost lib.

Comment: rand is working fine, you are only using it to fill the first 4 elements of the array

Comment: Note that you would have discovered this error immediately if you had used a memory debugger (like valgrind). If you see something unexpected in seemingly good code, it's always a good idea to debug a bit first.

Comment: Also, arr_s and arr_f are different variables -- where is arr_s defined?

Comment: Just a typo, I threw out some of the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void fillArray(int *arr){
    for(int i=0;i<(sizeof arr);i++){
```

Since `arr` is a pointer to an integer, `sizeof arr` is equivalent to `sizeof (int *)`, which is apparently 4 (32-bits) on your platform. That's clearly not what you want. You only pass `fillArray` a pointer to the first element of the array.

If you need the number of elements in the array a pointer points to, you need to pass that information. The C and C++ languages provides no way to tell how many bytes a pointer points to given just the pointer.

You do it correctly in `arrPoint`. Do it that way in `fillArray`.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays don't work like you think. You **cannot** use `sizeof` to get the array size magically. Arrays decay to pointers to their first element when passed as a function argument, and you *must* provide the size information separately:

```
int main()
{
  int * arr = new int[20];
  the_function(arr, 20);
  //...
  delete[] arr;
}

void (int * arr, std::size_t size)
{
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i)
  {
     // something with arr[i]
  }
}
```

Much better yet, use `std::vector<int>` to spare yourself all this headache, and tons of further headache that you may not even have thought about.

(There is an exception to my statement: For an automatic array in the local scope, `int b[10]`, `sizeof(b)` will indeed return `10 * sizeof(int)`. But that is only because the *compiler* knows the array size. The size information is not passed around, and it is not available at runtime.)

Answer (score 0):

In `fillArray` `(sizeof arr)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of your array.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `sizeof` operator. `arr` is a pointer to an `int`, which is usually 4 or 8 bytes long. You must pass the *length* of the array (not the size in bytes) as an additional parameter to the function.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `_countof(arr)` instead of `sizeof(arr)`.`_countof` returns size of array, not pointers-be aware of this.

Comment: -1: (a) this is Microsoft-specific and non-portable and, more importantly, (b) it won't work in this case since all the OP has is a pointer anyway